# templateUrl with cdn link angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular5

here is my component

import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dm-demo',
  templateUrl: 'http://localhost:99/index.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo.component.css'],
})
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I want to add templateUrl as an HTTP URL as above in code.
but not able to compile. Angular compiler gives error as below

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './http://localhost:99/index.html' in 'E:\code\demo\src\app\demo'

can anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: The best option would be use `http` request to get html file and use it in inline template, something like `div [innerHTML]="templateReceivedFromHttp">` remember to bypass it otherwise it won't display anything.

Comment: but I also add two binding in template @Szarik

Comment: Then I'm afraid you will have to find workaround for this. Maybe some nodejs script to get the file and store it in angular project?